# How to Change/Add Snippets for Atom?

Tags: html, atom-editor

How do I change or add snippets in atom?

I want to change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

To this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    
</head>
<body>

    
        
</body>
</html>
```

And I'd also like to know how to add snippets like these. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
> On your snippets.cson file add the following code: 
>'.text.html.basic':   'HTML':
>  'prefix': 'myhtml'
>  'body': '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n\n\t\t<meta charset="utf-8">\n\t\t<title></title>\n\n</head>\n<body>\n\n\n\n</body>\n</html>'
> 
> NOTE: value in the body section should be in one single line.
```